# Regarding the divisor function

Tags: number-theory

I have a hard time understanding why the divisor function for $n=p_1^{k_1}\cdot\cdot\cdot{p_r^{k_r}}$ equals to $$\sigma(n)=\prod_{1\leq i \leq r} \frac{p_i^{k_{i}+1}-1}{p_{i}-1}$$

Also why is $1+p_i+p_i^{2}+....+p_i^{k_i}=\frac{p_i^{k_i+1}-1}{p_{i}-1}$ $\quad$ I thought that this geometric sum (left-hand side) was equal to $$\frac{1-p_i^{k_i+1}}{1-p_i}$$

And also, would really appreciate if someone could explain me this (since we are already into number theory), regarding Wilsons theorem. In the proof in my textbook they write $(p-1)!=1\cdot{2}\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot{\frac{p-1}{2}}\cdot{\frac{p+1}{2}}\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot{(p-2)}\cdot{(p-1)}$. I can't really see how this can be true, how can we split up the factorial into quotients?

Comment: Are you asking why $\frac{p^{k+1}-1}{p-1}$ equals $\frac{1-p^{k+1}}{1-p}$?

Comment: If you expand $\prod_{1\leq i \leq r}(1+p_i+p_i^{2}+....+p_i^{k_i})$, you will find out that each term is a divisor of n, conversely every divisor of n is in the expansion of the product, and appears only once.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Yes that is one of my questions. They seem to differ with a factor of $-1$.

Comment: @PotatoHead47 Ok, but why do we take the product? Isn't $\sigma(n)$ the sum of the divisors?

Comment: If $p$ is an odd integer $\ge 3$, then $\frac{p-1}{2}$ and $\frac{p+1}{2}$ are two consecuve integers in $[1, p-1]$

Comment: $(p-1)!=1\cdot{2}\cdot3 \cdot\cdot\cdot{(p-2)}\cdot{(p-1)}$ by definition. He just splits the product to two parts. Notice that $\frac{p-1}{2}$ and $\frac{p+1}{2} $ are in the product iff $p$ is odd.

Comment: @fejz1234 So which one is positive, and which one is negative?

Comment: The expansion of the product will be a sum. For example: for $n=6$, we have $\sigma(n)= (1+2)(1+3) = 1\cdot1 + 2\cdot1 + 1\cdot3 + 2\cdot3$ which indeed the sum you're looking for.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Not sure what you mean with which one is positive or negative?

Comment: @PotatoHead47 Is there a way to realize why the sum generated by the expansion of the product is equal to the actual sum? This is what I have trouble with..

Comment: I will post it as an answer.

Comment: @fejz1234 If as you say, the two numbers differ by  a factor of $-1$, then surely one is positive, and the other negative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $n=p_1^{k_1}\cdot\cdot\cdot{p_r^{k_r}}$, then any divisor of n takes the form $m= p_1^{l_1}\cdot\cdot\cdot{p_r^{l_r}}$ where $0 \le l_i \le k_i$  for each $1\le
 i \le r$
By definition $$\sigma(n)  = \sum_{m|n} m $$ 
$$= \sum_{0 \le l_i \le k_i} (  p_1^{l_1}\cdot\cdot\cdot{p_r^{l_r}})$$ 
$$= (\sum_{0 \le l_i \le k_i}  p_1^{l_1})\cdot \cdot \cdot (\sum_{0 \le l_r \le k_r}  p_r^{l_r})$$ 
$$=\prod_{1\le i\le r}\sum_{l_i=0}^{k_i} p_i^{l_i}$$
$$=\prod_{1\le i\le r}\frac{1- p_i ^ {k_i+1}}{1-p_i}$$

Comment: Ok that makes sense. Also this is what I thought that the geometric sum should be equal to, why does my textbook have a factor of $-1$ of that quotient though?

$\frac{1-p_{i}^{k_{i}+1}}{1-p_i}$ isn't equal to $\frac{p_{i}^{k_{i}+1}-1}{p_{i}-1}$ ?

Comment: They are equal. Focus, dude!

Comment: Ah yeah true, haha that was obvious now..